# How to filter out columns when retrieveing data (Waterline)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I have a table with columns a,b,c,d. But I want to send to browser just data from a,b. Ive found it is possible to override `toJSON()` method but it seems to me this is a solution for 1-row results. How to make this work for array of jsons?

I could make my own function to iterate over the array and delete the unwanted properties but I feel like there should be a better solution for this.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're returning an array of instances using `res.json`, it will run `toJSON` on each instance in the array.  So:

```
User.find().exec(function(err, users) {
  if (err) {return res.negotiate(err);}
  return res.json(users);
});
```

will return an array of users with `toJSON` called on each one.

Comment: also be on the lookout for this hopefully in the near future https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/pull/509